# Sort a table of objects in Lua using one of its Classes

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I am trying to sort a table of objects in Lua, using one of its classes called `Name`.

In Python you could do something like this:

```
sorted_table = sorted(objects, key=lambda x: x.Name)
```

What would be the elegant way of doing this in Lua?

So far I have tried:

```
sorted_table = table.sort(objects, function(a,b) return a.name < b.name end))
```

but it is giving me this error:

```
[string "table.sort(objects, function(a,b) re..."]:1: attempt to compare two nil values
```

when I dump the table it look like this:

```
table: 000000000AF9BE40
    1 = Polygon (0x00000000194A5250) [App: 'Fusion' on 127.0.0.1, UUID: f60e6d62-b100-42f3-b5d4-5799ccf86136]
    2 = Polygon (0x000000001956EC60) [App: 'Fusion' on 127.0.0.1, UUID: f60e6d62-b100-42f3-b5d4-5799ccf86136]
    3 = Polygon (0x000000001956FAF0) [App: 'Fusion' on 127.0.0.1, UUID: f60e6d62-b100-42f3-b5d4-5799ccf86136]
    4 = Polygon (0x0000000019570980) [App: 'Fusion' on 127.0.0.1, UUID: f60e6d62-b100-42f3-b5d4-5799ccf86136]
    5 = Polygon (0x00000000194A43C0) [App: 'Fusion' on 127.0.0.1, UUID: f60e6d62-b100-42f3-b5d4-5799ccf86136]
```

As an example, if I print the following:

```
print(object[1].Name)
print(object[2].Name)
```

I get:

```
Name0001
Name0005
```

It is using these Names that I would like to sort my Table by

Comment: Add what the table looks like.

Comment: There is no `name` field in your objects.

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong field name:

```
sorted_table = table.sort(objects, function(a,b) return a.Name < b.Name end)
```

Also in your post you had two closing parents `))` surely just a typo in your post because that would be syntax error would have been flagged before the sort was executed.

Answer (score -1):

First copy table to new variable table, then sort it

see this page: http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable

```
function shallowcopy(orig)
    local orig_type = type(orig)
    local copy
    if orig_type == 'table' then
        copy = {}
        for orig_key, orig_value in pairs(orig) do
            copy[orig_key] = orig_value
        end
    else -- number, string, boolean, etc
        copy = orig
    end
    return copy
end


a={
    {name="Name0001"},
    {name="Name0004"},
    {name="Name0003"}
}
b=shallowcopy(a)
table.sort(b,function(aa,bb) return aa.name < bb.name end)
```

now b have sorted value

Comment: How can making a copy of the table solve the error about comparing nils?